# No suitable constructor found for ProductoExtranjero

Tags: java, constructor

I have this code and my problem is that it gives me an error in the methdod `CrearProductoExtranjero` in `ProductoExtranjeroPe = new ProductoExtranjero();` that says that the constructor isn't suitable, please help

```
import java.util.* ;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ProductoExtranjero extends Producto {
    private int PaisOrigen;

    public ProductoExtranjero(int PaisOrigen, String UnNombre, String UnRubro) {
        super(UnNombre, UnRubro);
        this.PaisOrigen = PaisOrigen;
    }

    public ProductoExtranjero(int PaísOrigen) {
        this.PaisOrigen = PaisOrigen;
    }

    public int getPaisOrigen() {
        return PaisOrigen;
    }

    public void setPaisOrigen(int PaísOrigen) {
        this.PaisOrigen = PaísOrigen;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return "ProductoExtranjero{" + "PaiedsOrigen=" + PaisOrigen + "nombre=" + this.getNombre() + "rubro=" + this.getRubro() ;
    }

     public static Producto CrearProductoExtranjero() {
        ProductoExtranjero Pe = new ProductoExtranjero();
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("ingrese País de origen (1-120)");
        Pe.setPaisOrigen(in.nextInt());
        boolean val= true;
        while(val){
        System.out.println("Ingrese un nombre del producto: ");
        Pe.setNombre(in.nextLine());
        int nomlargo;
        nomlargo=Pe.getNombre().length();
        if (nomlargo<=0){
            System.out.println("No ha ingresado un nombre producto valido. tiene que ser mayor a TRES!! caracteres.");
        }
        else{
            val=false;
        }
        }

        int opcion = 0;
        boolean entrar = true;
        while (entrar) {
            System.out.println("Ingrese el rubro del producto. Tomando en cuenta que: \n1.Limpieza \n2.Cosmetica "
                    + "\n3.Computacion \n4.Educacion \n5.Electrodomesticos \n6.Varios");
            opcion = in.nextInt();
            switch (opcion) {
                case 1:
                    Pe.setRubro("Limpieza");
                    entrar = false;
                   ;
                case 2:
                    Pe.setRubro("Cosmetica");
                    entrar = false;

                case 3:
                    Pe.setRubro("Computacion");
                    entrar = false;

                case 4:
                    Pe.setRubro("Educacion");
                    entrar = false;

                case 5:
                    Pe.setRubro("Electrodomesticos");
                    entrar = false;

                case 6:
                    Pe.setRubro("Varios");
                    entrar = false;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Ha ingresado un rubro no existente!!");



            } break;
        }
        return Pe;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Here are your two constructors:

```
public ProductoExtranjero(int PaisOrigen, String UnNombre, String UnRubro) {
    super(UnNombre, UnRubro);
    this.PaisOrigen = PaisOrigen;
}

public ProductoExtranjero(int PaísOrigen) {
    this.PaisOrigen = PaisOrigen;
}
```

Both of them have parameters. But this line:

```
ProductoExtranjeroPe = new ProductoExtranjero();
```

... is string to call a constructor without specifying any arguments.

You either need to specify a parameterless constructor, or specify arguments in your constructor call.

(I would also strongly recommend that you start following Java naming conventions.)

Comment: ok, so what do you mean by specify arguments in your constructor call?, cause what i want to do is to call that method in my main class so the user of the program can add productos extranjeros, i am new to programming thanx for the help and ill look at java naming conventions

Comment: @SantiagoMarquez: I mean `new ProductoExtranjero(10)` or something like that. To be honest, if you're very new to programming I would strongly recommend that you read a good book thoroughly. Stack Overflow is great for specific questions, but it's not a good way of learning the basics of a language.